# How to define the 'AT-POS' method?

Tags: operator-overloading, raku

I defined the `AT-POS` method for a class and exported the `[]` operator. 
When I used `[]` on the instance of that class, however, the compiler ignored the operator defined by me.

Here is the code:

```
unit module somelib;

class SomeClass is export {
    method AT-POS(@indices) {
        say "indices are {@indices.perl}"
    }
}

multi postcircumfix:<[ ]> (SomeClass:D $inst, *@indices) is export {
    $inst.AT-POS(@indices)
}
```

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl6

use v6.c
use lib ".";
use somelib;

my $inst = SomeClass.new;

$inst[3, 'hi'];

# expected output:
#   indices are 3, 'hi'

# actual output:
#   Type check failed in binding to parameter '@indices';
#   expected Positional but got Int (3)
#     in method AT-POS at xxx/somelib.pm6 (somelib) line 4
#     in block <unit> at ./client.pl6 line 8
```

So what is the problem with this code?

UPDATE:

I did need to pass more than one indices to the AT-POS method And I was quite surprised to find that using *$indices rather than *@indices gave the expected output when I was fixing a typo. I don't know there exists such usage like *$some-parameter. Is it valid or just a bug of the compiler?

```
unit module somelib;

class SomeClass is export {
    method AT-POS($indices) {
        say "indices are {$indices.perl}"
    }
}

multi postcircumfix:<[ ]> (SomeClass:D $inst, *$indices) is export {
    $inst.AT-POS($indices)
}
```

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl6

use v6.c;
use lib ".";
use somelib;

my $inst = SomeClass.new;

$inst[3, 'hi'];

# expected output:
#   indices are 3, 'hi' # or something like it 

# actual output:
#   indices are $(3, "hi") # It's ok for me.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that `AT-POS` is only expected to receive a single argument for a 1-dimensional `Positional`.  If you specify a slice, then the setting will take care of calling `AT-POS` multiple times and collect the results into a list:

```
class A {
    method AT-POS($a) { 2 * $a }
}
dd A.new[1,2,3,4];  # (2,4,6,8)
```

Also, you don't need to provide a `postcircumfix:<[ ]>` candidate, unless you really want to do very special things: the setting provided one will dispatch to the right `AT-POS` for you automagically.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. But please see the update for a surprising discovery.

Comment: Because you also created a `postcircumfix:<[ ]>` candidate for your object, it only follows the rules of that code (and thus bypasses any logic from the setting).  The `*$indices` **slurps** all parameters because of the `*` and puts them in a `List`.  Which is then passed to the `AT-POS` candidate.  Which receives the single `List` object and shows that.  The use of the slurpy `*` in that context is unusual, but valid, as far as I know.  It's just inconvenient most of the time, as a `List` object in a Scalar container will not iterate automatically.  Had you used the `@` sigil, it would have.