# Implementing AT-POS to return an object instead of a list of things

Tags: object, slice, raku

I've the following class:

```
class Names {
    has @!names;

    method add-name( $name ) { @!names.push($name) }

    multi method AT-POS( ::?CLASS:D: $index ) {
        my $new-names-obj = Names.new;

        for @!names[$index] -> $name {
            $new-names-obj.add-name($name);
        }

        return $new-names-obj;
    }

    method gist {
        @!names.join("\n")
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to slice a `Names` object and the returned value
should be another `Names` object whose elements are sliced off from the
original `Names` object. For instance:

```
my $original = Names.new;
$original.add-name($_) for <jonathan joseph jotaro josuke giorno>;
my $sliced-off = $original[0..2];

say $original.^name;   #=> Names
say $original;         #=> jonathan, joseph, jotaro, josuke, giorno
say $sliced-off.^name; #=> List
say $sliced-off;       #=> (jonathan joseph jotaro)
```

When a single argument is passed, it works as expected and as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54686741/10824322) but it's not the case with range since `AT-POS` ends up being called multiple times and collecting the results in a list. Thus I'm wondering if it's possible to return a single object `$sliced-off`, not a list of results, when using a range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on Liz's guidance:

```
class Names {
    has @.names;                                      # Make public so [] can access.
    method new (*@names) { nextwith :@names }         # Positional .new constructor.
    submethod BUILD (:@!names) {}                     # Called by nextwith'd Mu new.
    multi sub postcircumfix:<[ ]>                     # Overload [] subscript.
      ( Names $n, $index, *@indices )                 # Why `$index, *@indices`?
      is default is export                            # And why `is default`?
      { Names.new: |$n.names[ |$index, |@indices ] }  # Why? See my comment 
    method gist { @!names.join(', ') }                # below Liz's answer.
}
import Names;

my $original = Names.new: <jonathan joseph jotaro josuke giorno>;
my $sliced-off = $original[0..2];

say $original.^name;   #=> Names
say $original;         #=> jonathan, joseph, jotaro, josuke, giorno
say $sliced-off.^name; #=> Names
say $sliced-off;       #=> jonathan, joseph, jotaro
```

PLMK if the code or explanation is inadequate.

Comment: (part of me wonders if there's someway to get that autoexported making the `import` unnecessary.   It would be pretty awesome to be able to have classes define their own operators inside of them, although admittedly only a small space savings given most people just use modules which can export both the class and the operators together)

Comment: "have classes define their own operators" To clarify for other readers, you *can* do that -- that's what I've done. @user0721090601 "autoexported" Presumably `@Larry` felt it best to require *something* explicit to trigger import. "someway" There's *always* a way. :) I'm not convinced it'd be worth it. But here's a couple ideas. Maybe `sub trait_mod:<is> (Mu $package, :$exported!) { ... trigger import once package composed ... }; class foo is exported { ... }`? Or [this is the hook for introducing new declarators](https://github.com/jnthn/oo-monitors/blob/master/lib/OO/Monitors.pm6#L111-L115).

Comment: Indeed, I meant to be "define and autoexport".  But thinking about it a bit more, only certain operators can be assumed to work as designed by a given class's author.  Namely `~~`, `eqv`, and a few others (because `~~` uses `ACCEPTS`, and `eqv` can use `WHICH`, etc).  If I define a custom `+` infixes for my `Supercomplex` numeric class, there's no guarantee, though, that it will be called when it gets passed along to a math module that doesn't know about it.  Even autoexporting/importing won't solve that.

Comment: @user0721090601 Right. The semantics for how an overall op turns into a particular detailed sequence of sub operations is arbitrary -- sometimes simple to overload, sometimes not. And iirc all non-method operators and their overloads are lexical. So you have to do something more drastic than mere `import` to make a difference to what happens when operators are called in other modules. Something like rebinding an operator's definition in the `CORE::` namespace -- and that's definitely a pretty drastic thing to do just so you can sneak in your own variation for your own type! :)

Comment: This code no longer seems to work (Raku version 2020.04). I get the error: "Index out of range. Is: 1, should be in 0..0". Any directions how to make it work? ([Elizabeth's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60045041/14163984) solution works, but I want class-based solution.)

Comment: @AntonAntonov I'm guessing you meant 2022.04, right?

Comment: @raiph Yes, I meant 2022.04. I am trying to resolve this issue:https://github.com/antononcube/Raku-Data-Reshapers/issues/1 . After I forked [`Pretty::Table`](https://gitlab.com/uzluisf/raku-pretty-table/) -- written by OP -- I found the error in my previous comment.

Answer (score 8):

The `AT-POS` method is intended to let an object act as a `Positional` object.  This is *not* what you appear to want.  You want `object[slice]` DWIM.

The best way to achieve that, is to create a `postcircumfic:<[ ]>` (multi) candidate for your object:

```
class A {
    method slice(@_) {
        say @_;  # just to show the principle
    }
}
sub postcircumfix:<[ ]>($object, *@indices) {
   constant &slicer = &postcircumfix:<[ ]>;
   $object ~~ A
     ?? $object.slice(@indices)
     !! slicer($object, @indices)
}

A.new[1,2,4,5];  # [1 2 4 5]

my @a = ^10;     # check if foo[] still works
say @a[1,2,4,5]; # (1 2 4 5)
```

To make sure that the common behaviour of `@a[]` is kept, we save the value of the system's `postcircumfix:[ ]>` at compile time (with a `constant`).  Then at runtime, when the object is *not* of the right class, invoke the original version of `postcircumfix:<[ ]>` with the given parameters.

Comment: `A.new[1,2,4,5];` doesn't print the positions being passed, however calling `.slice([1,2,4,5])` on the newly created object does. It's as if the indexes aren't being passed to `.slice` when using `[]`. Another thing is that using `[]` with a single index throws the error `Index out of range. Is: 1, should be in 0..0`.

Comment: I can't seem for some reason to get the new sub to be called on my end, even when using `is default`.  Changing it to `[_ _]` (and the resulting call) does work, however.

Comment: In my tests, use of postcircumfix `[...]` does not call the sub Liz has defined. To get it to work I had to use `multi sub postcircumfix:<[ ]> ( A:D $object, $index ) { ... } {}` and to get it to work *usefully* (taking multiple index args) it had to be `multi sub postcircumfix:<[ ]> ( A:D $object, $index, *@rest ) is default { $object.slice( [ $index, |@rest ] ) }`.

Comment: Yeah, I got caught in adding the `multi` later.  If you take away the `multi`, it *does* work like I said.  But then you can't slice any ordinary arrays anymore.  Hmmm...

Comment: This also reminds me that for strongly typed Raku, having a typed slice would be kind of useful.  Doing `Array[T].new: @object[slice]` does get old after a while.  Actually, maybe I'll make that as a quick little module to do that.  `sub postcircumfix:<[[ ]]> ( Positional \p, \items) is equiv(&postcircumfix:<[ ]>)  { p.WHAT.new: p[items.list] }` does the trick 99.99% of the time methinks (it'd *technically* fail if someone designed a `Positional` that didn't have a `.new` accepting a list, but that's just weird)

Comment: For some reason I've been unable to make it work with the [target class](https://modules.raku.org/dist/Pretty::Table:cpan:UZLUISF/lib/Pretty/Table.rakumod) but ultimately I think it has to do with the way the class is designed. Fortunately, raiph's answer did the trick.